# Idea to promote more traffic to non-technical related Stack Exchange sites

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-exchange, site-crossover, sharing

The moderator/founder of one of the Stack Exchange sites I frequent, [Basically Money](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions), frequently tweets links to questions on [his feed](http://twitter.com/BasicallyMoney). This got me thinking that perhaps a way to solve the dilemma of bringing an audience to the Stack Exchange sites that don't have cross-over appeal with programmers is to make better use of social media.

Why not add a sharing link to the bottom of each question (maybe even answers too) so you can easily re-post them to Facebook, Twitter, Digg, etc.?

For example, on some of the Do-It-Yourself Stack Exchange sites the traffic was so poor that it wasn't even worth posting the question, but I still felt a desire to support the site and help bootstrap it. If I could post the question anyway, then easily share it on Facebook or Twitter then I could still leverage my own social network for answers AND get the benefit of all the cool voting/commenting features of the Stack Exchange platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean like the text that was at the bottom of this very question? (only appears when there are no answers yet)

> #### Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via email, twitter, or facebook.

Or like the existing share buttons on every single Stack Exchange 2.0 site?

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/

Or like the Booster, Announcer, and Publicist badges that exist?

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/

Comment: Umm, yeah. But that wasn't there when I posted the suggestion back in June.

Comment: @john ah, sorry missed that :) Well, status-completed! yay!