# Will the links to share a question on Facebook and Tweet be adopted in other Q&A sites?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is It that Facebook and Twitter Sharing Button Not Available on SOFU Sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62077/why-is-it-that-facebook-and-twitter-sharing-button-not-available-on-sofu-sites)

On [English Language and Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com) in each question there are links to share it on Facebook, and Tweet.
Will be these links add to other Q&A sites?

Comment: The question is slightly different; it is asking if those links will ever be adopted in other Q&A sites, which means in non beta sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote [Jeff's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62077/why-is-it-that-facebook-and-twitter-sharing-button-not-available-on-sofu-sites/62089#62089) in the question linked by ChrisF above:

> Because these sites are no longer in
>   public beta.

This would indicate that it's currently only available for sites in public beta. So to answer your question:

"if those links will ever be adopted in other Q&A sites, which means in non beta sites"

The answer is no.