# Twitter & Facebook share links missing

Tags: support, facebook, twitter, social-networking

Sometimes the Twitter and Facebook share buttons are missing on my own posts. (The ones under the favourite icon.)

Why is this?
I want to get share my posts with my twitter followers, as usually I get better responses.

---

**Note:** The sharing buttons are also available on SOFU now (but not on the meta sites).

Comment: On which particular Stack Exchange site are you talking about?

Comment: Stack Overflow. Isn't this just Meta Stack Overflow?

Comment: It also covers problems, feature requests etc for all the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: This Meta site is kind of special. In addition to questions about Stack Overflow in particular, it also serves as the "main" Meta site for the entire Stack Exchange network. So both are on topic, unlike regular site metas.

Comment: That's not a bug, that's a feature!

Comment: See also [Why are the facebook and twitter sharing buttons not available on SOFU sites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/62077) (possible duplicate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the [Stack Exchange 2.0 sites](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/twitter-question-feeds-for-stack-exchange/) have automatic Facebook- and Twitter-sharing buttons. The sites that make up the "original trilogy" (Stack Overflow, Server Fault, and Super User) don't have this integration.

You'll have to share the question yourself if it's posted on one of those three sites.

I've been told that the [Facebook bookmarklet](http://www.facebook.com/share_options.php) is a nice option. Or see [this comprehensive list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5188/what-third-party-tools-are-there-for-the-trilogy-websites) of third-party tools available for the trilogy websites.

Comment: Ok. Then how do I shorten the URL? E.g. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QDe3Fy7o2wc&feature=topvideos_entertainment => http://youtu.be/QDe3Fy7o2wc

Comment: @Adam: http://goo.gl/ ?

Comment: Oh you see I thought SO used it's own short URL address. I had never seen t.co before

Comment: @Adam: They might for the SE 2.0 sites that have the social networking integration. I've honestly never used either of those features, so I can't say for certain. But there isn't any such thing for Stack Overflow in particular. At least not yet.

Comment: Has this just changed?

Comment: @Andrew: Yes - recently changed.