# Can I hide the sharing buttons?

Tags: discussion, user-interface, sharing

Can I hide any of the sharing buttons? I don't use LinkedIn or Facebook to share questions, but I occasionally use Twitter.

Comment: I'd like to see a pref to just hide them all away, including the disturbing "Know someone who can answer?" phrase at bottom of an unanswered question.

Comment: @Chichiray: Why does that disturb you?

Comment: I'm not social. And I like clean UI.

Comment: Sadly, [the "original trilogy" doesn't have Twitter integration, but the Stack Exchange 2.0 sites do.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91749/twitter-facebook-share-links-missing/91754#91754)

Comment: @Chris: is that still the case?

Comment: @Andrew: Huh, you're right. I'm seeing the links but [it doesn't appear to be documented as a recent feature change](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445/162705)?

Comment: @Chris Jeff likely turned it on after last week's podcast, where this particular feature not being enabled on Stack Overflow was discussed.

Comment: Well shame on me for not listening to [the podcast](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/se-podcast-16/).  :)

Comment: Those social buttons and the banner add way too much visual noise.  I hide them with chrome adblock, but I'd rather an official option to disable them.

Comment: Not to mention that the mere presence of the FB share button allows Facebook to track your web activity.  If you don't have a FB account it creates "shadow" IDs instead.  Random User Agent plug-ins provide some protection but will not remove the cookies.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's as far not possible without [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/), [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) or like. You could then hide them with some CSS rules:

```css
a.fb-share, a.twitter-share, a.linkedin-share { display: none; }
```

I would however opt for a global pref to hide them altogether.

[image]

---

## Update (almost 1 year later)

They have **finally** been removed from the UI! They are now only available behind the "share" link.

[image]

\o/

Comment: If they don't make it configurable without Greasemonkey, then they're making it more likely to Greasemonkey it, which'd be a bit of an unintended outcome.

Comment: It also works in a plain usercss stylesheet if you add the `!important` thingy.

Comment: AdBlock works well too.

Comment: Adblock claims to be able to do if you add the "fanboy" filter list

Answer (score 11):

Install AdBlock Plus for Chrome or Firefox and add a couple of rules:

```
stackoverflow.com##.fb-share
stackoverflow.com##.twitter-share
stackoverflow.com##.linkedin-share
stackoverflow.com##.gp-share
stackoverflow.com##.bottom-notice
stackoverflow.com##.share-answer
```

Comment: Works nicely, although it won't be a permanent solution (as stuff gets changed around on the site).

Comment: AdBlock has a "create easy filter" button where you highlight crap you dont want to see anymore so if they add more annoying stuff it will be easy to remove. And it works with Chrome sync so its saved across your different computers.

Comment: Or a more compact rule: `stackoverflow.com##[class$="-share"],.share-answer`. Note that "bottom-notice" is unrelated to the sharing stuff, some people might want to keep it.

Answer (score 11):

This adds a tremendous amount of visual clutter to the interface, thus distracting from the question itself.  I propose that the sharing interface should be added as a drop-down when hovering over a share button. Here's a quick mockup (complete with hand-drawn button):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Not officially but a [couple a weeks ago](https://stackapps.com/questions/2562/a-few-tweaks-to-the-user-interface-of-stack-overflow) I created a Google Chrome extension called [undercurrent](http://stf.planet.ee/undercurrent/).

[image: undercurrent]

Its latest version (1.0.7) contains **an option to hide the sharing buttons**. You can download the extension from [undercurrent website](http://stf.planet.ee/undercurrent/).

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use extensions, Firefox also allows you to put a `userContent.css` file into the `chrome/` subdirectory of [your profile](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Profiles#w_how-do-i-find-my-profile). It should have the following contents:

```
@-moz-document domain(stackoverflow.com) {
  .fb-share,
  .twitter-share,
  .linkedin-share,
  .share-answer {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Note that changes to `userContent.css` only become effective after a browser restart. If you don't like this, Stylish or Adblock Plus are the way to go as other people noted already.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question directly, but these sharing buttons were supposedly added after [SE Podcast #16](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/se-podcast-16/). [As Chichiray said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105304/can-i-configure-the-sharing-buttons/105305#105305), though, there's currently no option for disabling them.

[image: Question with Facebook, Twitter, and LinkedIn share buttons]

Comment: I understood that he was well aware about this and that his question was more about the possibility to just hide the Facebook and Linkedin buttons by configuration (is it?).

Comment: @Chichiray: Yes. Bathwater, baby, getting rid of.

Comment: @Chris: Yes. And thanks for fixing "occasionally"!