# I like Stack Exchange. How can I express it?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange

I have used Stack Exchange for the last two weeks, and I find it very very useful. Is there any way I can express my "like" towards this website?

I mean, if I find an interesting page in Facebook, I can press the "Like" button to express my happiness towards that web page.

How can I do the same here with Stack Exchange?

Or

Is there any button I can press and share this website with others?
I mean, like "Facebook share"?

Otherwise, you can take this as feedback from a new user and work on it.

Comment: You can contribute. Ask, answer, edit, review...

Comment: nowadays when searching in google, I use stackexchange after my keyword, Good Job Stackexchange team.

Comment: I saw a advertisement for promotion of stackexchange facebook page in one of the stackexchange website. Was it implemented before or after my suggestion ?

Answer (score 9):

Well, Stack Exchange maintains official pages in three social networks so far.

1. [Google+](https://plus.google.com/+StackExchange/posts) - feel free to Follow and share with your friends/followers.
2. [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/stackexchange) - feel free to Like and share the page with your friends and family.
3. [Twitter](https://twitter.com/stackexchange) - feel free to Follow and share wih your own followers.

However, the greatest gratitude would be becoming active member, ask good questions and/or post awesome answers all around the network. :-)

Answer (score 8):

If your main concern is to share with others there is a `share` button under each and every post on the site:

[image]

(Picture taken from BalusC's [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105305/241526). Bird in the original.)

Comment: This is to share a question. But what I am looking for is a kind of "simple way to express my thanks/likes/Gratitude".