# "link" below question or answer

Tags: discussion, support

What does basically "link" below question/answer do ?

For me - just page is being refreshed. It gives tool-tip as"**Permalink to this question/answer**". Actually I am not getting the function of this. Would someone please explain this ?

Why there isn't a facility like, Hey Check out - this is new cool feature available & demo video or something like that demonstrating it. While adding tags to this question, I found one more addition to StackOverflow, tag automatically shows up after typing.
I came to know about this feature, After I used it. Isn't there something like, hey just watchout here - new cool/awesome feature now & use it like this. new/Blog is pretty uncool to get updates about new features added suddenly.

Comment: Please don't edit your old question for a new question. (See also [Idea to promote more traffic to non-technical related Stack Exchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54184/idea-to-promote-more-traffic-to-non-technical-related-stack-exchange-sites/72563#72563).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can copy this link and post it somewhere else. Link below the answer gives a handy way to have a link to particular answer and not all answers, when there are many

Comment: Yep ! Got the point.